# How to find match in sequence with nested sets? (or nested anything else)

Tags: python-3.x, nested, match, sequence

I got sequence with sets inside, like this:
`[1234, 'abc', 'def', {123, 'abc'}, 567]`

I want to create function searching for match in sequence and inside sets. It of course start like this:

`for element in sequence:
    if element == condition:
        do_something()`

Than I wrote second part:

    `elif condition in element
        do_something()`

But here I got error, because:
`TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

I understand this error. But how can I do what I want? If there is this error, it means, that there is no match, and it should go to another element, checking if it is iterable. How can I force program to do this?

In the end, I don't want to check just `sequence[3]` for condition, because I don't know, how sequence will look like. It can have different length and different elements in different position. I also don't know how condition will look like, will it be int, string, sequence, set or float. But I guess it's not a problem here.

Maybe it's way to check if element in sequence is iterable? I would be able to do another `if` and check condition inside element only if this element is iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have arbitrary nesting, you should look at doing this recursively. (Google 'Python Flatten (an irregular) list of lists')

Since this is tagged Python 3, you can write something like:

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(l):
   for e in l:
       if isinstance(e, Iterable) and not isinstance(e, str):
           yield from flatten(e)
       else:
           yield e 

li=[1234, 'abc', 'def', {123, 'abc'}, 567]        

for e in ('abc', 'abd', 123, 124):        
    print(e in flatten(li))     
    # True, False, True, False
```